# Relacionar dos diccionarios C#

Tags: c#, diccionarios

Tengo dos archivos de textos con los siguientes datos (separado por tabuladores):

**CLIENTE**

```
ID_CLIENTE  CLIENTE MERCADO
1198        CTA           G
1285        FGF           B
1112        EJESA         B
1131        ESPERANZA     F
1150        NORP          B
1141        LUQUE         B
1151        TUCU          F
1235        BERNV         G
```

**GASTO**

```
FECHA           ID_CLIENTE  GASTO
01/08/2017      1198        25647   
01/08/2017      1285        4885
01/08/2017      1112        71987
01/08/2017      1131        1000
01/08/2017      1150        5
01/08/2017      1141        98
01/08/2017      1151        84
01/08/2017      1235        5899
02/08/2017      1198        257 
02/08/2017      1285        4885
02/08/2017      1112        1987
02/08/2017      1131        1489
02/08/2017      1150        5489
02/08/2017      1141        8
02/08/2017      1151        841
02/08/2017      1235        589
03/08/2017      1198        257 
03/08/2017      1285        4
03/08/2017      1112        1987
03/08/2017      1131        1589
03/08/2017      1150        2489
03/08/2017      1141        89
03/08/2017      1151        841
03/08/2017      1235        589
```

Ya cree una clase para cada archivo e individualicé los datos.

```
public class Cliente
    {
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Mercado { get; set; }
    }


public class Consumo
    {
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public int Gasto { get; set; }
    }
```

Lo que necesito hacer es tomar el maximo gasto de cada cliente e imprimirlo en un archivo de texto. Debo hacerlo con Diccionarios.

Declaración:

```
List<Cliente> Clientes;
List<Consumo> Consumos;

Dictionary<int, Cliente> dClientes;
Dictionary<int, List<Consumo>> dConsumos;

#region Constructor

public Reporte(List<Cliente> Clientes, List<Consumo> Consumos)
{
    this.Clientes = Clientes;
    this.Consumos = Consumos;
}

#endregion
```

Carga de datos a Diccionarios:

```
 dClientes = Clientes.ToDictionary(c => c.IdCliente, v => v);


        dConsumos = Consumos.Where(c => dClientes.Keys.Contains(c.IdCliente)).
            GroupBy(c => c.IdCliente).
            ToDictionary(c => c.Key, v => v.ToList<Consumo>());
```

**Mi pregunta es:** Como relaciono (INNER JOIN a ID_CLIENTE) ambos diccionarios para poder realizar dicha operacion (mayor gasto)  o qué tipo de métodos se utilizan en estos casos. Si se puede realizar dicha operación en un método aparte y luego implementarlo sería mejor.

**SALIDA ESPERADA**

```
CLIENTE    MERCADO  MAXIMO GASTO
CTA           G          2547
FGF           B          4885
EJESA         B          71987
ESPERANZA     F          1589
NORP          B          5489
LUQUE         B          98
TUCU          F          841
BERNV         G          5899
```

Un saludo, cualquier duda o arreglo a la pregunta estoy a disposición.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para hacer lo que pides, debes hacer uso del método [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Proyecta cada elemento de una secuencia en un IEnumerable y reduce las secuencias resultantes en una secuencia.

La consulta es un poco compleja, y habrá que agrupar dos veces por `IdCliente` ya que puede darse el caso de que el gasto máximo de un cliente se repita. Mas o menos sería algo como esto:

```
var dConsumos = Consumos.Where(c => dClientes.Keys.Contains(c.IdCliente))
                        .GroupBy(x => x.IdCliente)
                        .SelectMany(b => b.Where(c => c.Gasto == b.Max(d => d.Gasto)))
                        .GroupBy(x => x.IdCliente)
                        .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, v => v.ToList<Consumo>());
```

Es posible que haya alguna forma mas sencilla de hacerlo, pero creo que esta funciona correctamente.

**Edit**

Para imprimir los datos conseguidos pero mostrando además campos que están en `Clientes` tienes varias opciones. Aquí te pongo una muy sencilla sin tener que tocar la consulta:

```
foreach (var maximo in dConsumos)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", dClientes[maximo.Key].NombreCliente, dClientes[maximo.Key].Mercado, maximo.Value.First().Gasto);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Pikoh. ¿Y como imprimo esos datos por pantalla?

 var grouping = ... 
foreach(var k in grouping){
fc.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", /* Llamar a las variables */)
}

Comment: `k` es de tipo `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, solo haz `k.Value` o `k.Key` para acceder al valor o la llave respectivamente.

Comment: k.Key me devuelve el IdCliente, pero k.Value me devuelve: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Problema3.Consumo] .

Comment: ¿Y qué otra cosa debe retornar?

Comment: @NaCl k.Value tendría que devolverme el Máximo gasto de cada cliente.